# pass parameter to Angular directive template function post-post-link, using $scope, GET or whatever

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a directive that will format content for modal display (using Bootstrap classes) if given a certain parameter, and as standard view if not. I have this working for a view loaded directly, toggling on a URL param (`?modal`) available to `$routeParams` and/or `$location`.

I want to use this toggle-able template as a "pipe" for other templates. However, the intended content URL will never be the visible URL when used as a modal. I can't get it working when loading the view with `$modal.open` or `ngInclude`, because `$routeParams`/`$location` has data for the *including* page, not the *included* one.

I put this in a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RpXUYQxbn9YI6bVN2KU6?p=preview), but because Plunker also doesn't provide the URL param, the modal view isn't available.

Does Angular provide a means to change the template or `templateUrl` much later in the process? For example, could I use `$scope`, either from a controller or on the directive, itself?

**Clarification**: The goal here is to have *one* template/partial for each component, with that template used either as a standalone or a modal, based on some switch. The `_modal` and `_alone` partials in the Plunker convert the component template into the desired state.

Answer (score 0):

$modal.open takes a single object parameter one of the properties of this config parameter is templateUrl

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

So you can create the config object and open the modal with any template you need.

Dan Wahlin uses this technique for a dialog service and then in this article goes on to demonstrate a full modal service

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service

Comment: I added clarification to my question. Yes, this works, but I'd need separate standalone and modal partials for each component. I want a standalone template and modal template, through with the partials are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues with your code:

First of all the use `$routeParams` if you don't use `ngRoute`'s `$routeProvider`.
In your case, it might be easier to use `$window.location.search` (and compare it against `?modal`).

That said, in order to properly display a Bootstrap modal, you need Bootstrap's JS file (which in turn requires jQuery) and you also need to create the modal (e.g. by calling `$('.modal').modal()`).

---

Take a look at this **[modified demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vmupk3wuS40EZ0H41YB8?p=preview)**.

---

<sub>For better intergration with Angular's components, you might want to look into **[UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)**.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup. With BS.js, the modal works.
UI Bootstrap is what provides $modal, mentioned in my question.

Comment: $location.search has the same problem: it is based on the including page, not the included.

Comment: @N13: I don't knwo what you mean. My modified demo works so I don't know what issue you are referring to (maybe I misunderstood the question). BTW, I never said you should use `$location.search()`; I said `$window.location.search` (which is totally different).

Comment: Yours works because you're not including index.html into another view, so the URL is the page wanted as a modal. Add another page/view, tell it to `ngInclude` or `$modal` index, and you'll get the default/non-modal version. I think I tried both `$location` and `$window.location`. The documentation even says "The $location service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based on the window.location) and makes the URL available to your application."